# Set data in JSP in dynamic way using Ajax

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to put data into JSP page from JSON object using `js or jquery`

Fetching data from database using ajax, after getting success response set data in fields

```
function loadCustomerDetails(url) {
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        global : false,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        async : false,
        success : function(data) { // Here data is json object
            initCustomerDetails(data);          
    });

    return result;
}

function initCustomerDetails(data) {
    $("#firstName").text(data.firstName);
    $("#lastName").text(data.lastName);
    $("#dob").text(data.dob);

    ....
    Other fields set here (I have almost 50 fields that I need to set here)
}
```

Above code is working fine but the issue is maintaining the code because any field is added then I have to modify code here.

So is there any other better way for setting the data?

I am using below JSP

```
<form id="customer" name="customer" method="POST">
    <tr id="detailstrid5" align="left">
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name= "firstName"></input>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name= "lastName"></input>
        <input type="text" id="dob" name= "dob"></input>

        ...
        ...
        Other fields
      </td>
    </tr>

  </form>
```

> Note : I am using JSP + Java + Spring MVC + JS + JQuery + AJAX

Comment: You can also create form fields after getting data from server by iterating that data. For each field of the data you can create input field.

Comment: Can you please share one example

Answer (score 0):

You can try something below:

```
function loadCustomerDetails(url) {
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        global : false,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        async : false,
        success : function(data) { // Here data is json object
            populateFormFields(data);          
    });

    return result;
}


function populateFormFields(data){
        for(var prp in data){
          var inputElement =document.createElement('input');
          inputElement.setAttribute('type','text');
          inputElement.setAttribute('id',prp);
          inputElement.setAttribute('name',prp);
          document.getElementById('yourTdId').appendChild(inputElement);
        }
      initCustomerDetails(data);
}
```

Comment: It will create new element everytime .. but I have already those element in jao page...

Comment: Before for loop you can remove td element childs.

Comment: Any other options

Comment: Sorry I showed you a way to think. For your detailed needs try google